# This site can’t be reached

Tags: magento-1.9, api

I've been having difficulties accessing my site all it display is :

> This site can’t be reached

`www.obeezi.com` took too long to respond, Search Google for obeezi admin `8gh6g1 ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Answer (score 2):

I am able to access this site .

May be your browser issue,

check in different browser or in `privet mode`

or else check your firewall for blocking this site

[image]

Comment: thanks bro, that's the main site everybody can access but the magento that is meant for the administrator is not going through

Comment: @Johnbrainy can you give me admin url